# How to tell pointer's current x-y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, I would like to find the x-y coordinates of cursor pointer on the screen in a HTML webpage.

Comment: Have you searched at all for this? Resources exist for this everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you the current x-y coordinates.(displayed in console)

```js
function move(e){
  console.log("x" + e.clientX); 
    console.log("y" + e.clientY);
}
```

```css
 .box{     
      width: 600px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="box" onmousemove="move(event)">

 </div>
</body>
```